# How do i execute code when i select an option in blazor

Tags: html, forms, blazor

I am trying to execute a method when i select a option but i can't figure out how to do this.

this is what i am trying right now the `<InputSelect/>` is in an `<EditForm/>` object:

```
<tr>
   <th>
      <label for="layouts">Layout *</label><br />
      <InputSelect @bind-Value="label.Layout">
            <option value="">Selecteer</option>
            <option value="@availableLayouts.GetValue(0)" @onselect="OnSelectFinalCheck">Eindcontrole</option>
            <option value="@availableLayouts.GetValue(1)" @onselect="OnSelectStock">Voorraad</option>
            <option value="@availableLayouts.GetValue(2)">Uitbesteed werk</option>
            <option value="@availableLayouts.GetValue(3)">Geleidebon label</option>
        </InputSelect>
      <br />
   </th>
<th>
```

So this is my selection and when i click "voorraad" i want to execute a method.

Comment: What are you trying to do. Note: InputSelect must be within an EditForm. It can't be used otherwise. Use the select element instead, if you don't use the Editform

Comment: I have edited the question, i am using EditForm in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: The onselect event fires after some text has been selected in an element. It has nothing to do with the select element or selection of options...
As far as I remember, the InputSelect had some issues, but these may have already been dealt with by the Blazor team.

The following code snippet describes how you can use the select element in Blazor, and how to implement a two-way data binding; that is, from a variable to an element, and from an element to a variable. You can do that in various ways: my code employs the most efficient way to achieve this goal, according to maestro Steve Anderson.

Here's the code snippet that bind the SelectedAuthorID variable to the select element employing two-way data binding.

```
 <select @bind="@SelectedAuthorID">
    <option value=@(0)></option>
    @foreach (var author in authors)
    {
        <option value="@author.ID">@author.Name</option>
    }
</select>
```

Note: The SelectedAuthorID is a property which defines a backing private variable:

```
    int _selectedAuthorID;
    private int SelectedAuthorID
    {
        get => _selectedAuthorID;
        set
        {
            if (_selectedAuthorID != value)
            {
                _selectedAuthorID = value;
            }
        }
     }
```

Well, this code is quite self-explanatory, but if you're not completely understand what I did, don't hesitate to ask.

The authors object in the foreach loop above is a list of authors you can create as follows:

```
 @code {
     List<Author> authors= Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => new Author { ID 
                            = i, Name = $"Author {i.ToString()}" }).ToList();

 public class Author
 {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

}

Now, let's try to model my options after the  `value="@availableLayouts.GetValue(1)"` expression . This expression is evaluated to a string literal, right ? And when the user select this option, the OnSelectStock is called to do something.

Let's say that we want to call an OnSelectStock method and pass it the author id when an author is selected, and his id is even. Thus we can do something like this:

```
    if (_selectedAuthorID != value)
        {
            _selectedAuthorID = value;
            if(value % 2 == 0)
            {
                OnSelectStock( value );
            }

        }
```

This is it.

Hope this helps...

Complete working code:

### Index.razor

```
@page "/"

<select @bind="@SelectedAuthorID">
    <option value=@(0)></option>
    @foreach (var author in authors)
    {
        <option value="@author.ID">@author.Name</option>
    }
</select>

<p>Selected Author ID: @authorID</p>

@code{

string authorID;

int _selectedAuthorID;
private int SelectedAuthorID
{
    get => _selectedAuthorID;
    set
    {
        if (_selectedAuthorID != value)
        {
            _selectedAuthorID = value;
      // Call OnSelectStock only if the author ID is an even number
            if (value % 2 == 0)
            {
                OnSelectStock(value);
            }
        }
    }
 }

 List<Author> authors = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => new Author 
                { ID = i, Name = $"Author {i.ToString()}" }).ToList();

 private void OnSelectStock(int value)
 {
    authorID = value.ToString();
 }

 public class Author
 {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
 }
}
```

Comment: This looks like it could work but i cant even get this part to work it says on `<option value="@author.ID">@author.Name</option>` that: The 'author` directive must appear on the start of the line. Got any idea as to why it is saying that?

Comment: Yes, I've got an idea why she's saying that ... I've assembled the code snippets into a working sample. I'll put it at the end of my answer. Just copy it into your Index component and run it...